# does Chromium version sync with google chrome version

Tags: chrome

Today when I download Chromium from https://download-chromium.appspot.com. when I open the downloaded app, I found the Chromium version is `Version 92.0.4515.107 (Official Build) (x86_64)`. Now the google chrome version is 99, why the Chromium version still 92 ? is it possible to get Chromium 99?  I did not found any 99 verison of Chromium to download. this is the download url: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Mac/974466/chrome-mac.zip . After unpack the download file,there is only one file like this:

[image]

when I open the file, shows version is 92.xxxxxx.

Comment: The zip I get has `101.0.4907.0` in the `Chromium.app/info.plist` and `Chromium.app/Contents/Frameworks/Chromium Framework.framework/Versions`.

Comment: I have only one file when unzip the package.@muru

Comment: You can right click the app and use "Show Package Contents" to see those files.